# Result Set keeps getting null pointer when executing prepared statement but not when debugging and stepping thourgh

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I am running a prepared statement querying a MySQL database. I am fetching around 500 rows from this query. When mapping the entries in the result set to my data model object I keep getting random null pointers for some of the row elements. However, if I debug the code as it is executing and step through even just a couple of rows the data is correctly mapped to the data model. It seems as if it is executing to quickly but I am not sure whats going on. Any hel is much appreciated.

```
prep = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DAILY_SUMMARY_BY_PLAYER WHERE CLIENT_ID=? AND DATE = ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY NUM_BETS desc");

        prep.setInt(1,clientId);
        prep.setString(2,dateFrom);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            report = new ReportData();

            report.setAccount_id(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ACCOUNT_ID")));
            report.setClient_id(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("CLIENT_ID")));
            report.setClient_name(clientService.getClient(rs.getInt("CLIENT_ID")).getClientName());
            report.setDate(rs.getString("DATE").substring(0,10));
            report.setSite_id(rs.getString("SKIN_ID"));
            report.setGame_type(rs.getString("GAME_TYPE"));
            report.setGame_version(""+rs.getInt("GAME_VERSION"));
            report.setMobile(""+rs.getInt("MOBILE_DESKTOP"));

            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(rs.getString("NUM_BETS"));
            report.setNum_bets(formatter.format(bd.doubleValue()));

            bd = new BigDecimal(rs.getString("PL"));
            report.setPl(formatter.format(bd.doubleValue()));

            bd = new BigDecimal(rs.getString("RETURNS"));
            report.setReturns(formatter.format(bd.doubleValue()));

            bd = new BigDecimal(rs.getString("STAKED"));
            report.setStaked(formatter.format(bd.doubleValue()));

            reportList.add(report);
        }            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(""+e);
        logger.error(""+e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        try {
            if(rs != null){
                rs.close();
                rs  = null;
            }
            if(prep != null){
                prep.close();
                prep = null;
            }
            if(con != null){
                con.close();
                con = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(""+e);
            logger.error(""+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    return reportList;
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: can you share your error please?

Comment: Is any of the ReportData class fields a primitive (e.g. an int insetad of Integer)? If so, then you're probably trying to assing a null value to a primitive, which doesn't work.